# Cross-Compiling kernel can't find gcc

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, gcc, make

I am cross compiling the Raspbian kernel since it will take about 12 hours for the Pi to do (Raspberry Pi 1).

I have the build tools for ARM and the kernel in two separate folders in /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/

I am following this guide: http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation

My issue is that when I go to compile, it can't find arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3 which is clearly in the folder I linked when I did export CCPREFIX. Here is what I did:

```
gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ export CCPREFIX=/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

And it returns when I try to build:

```
gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: 1: /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3: not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: 1: /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3: not found
Kbuild:43: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
Makefile:990: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Even though the file is clearly in there:

[image: Even though the file is clearly in there]

Thanks.

Comment: Try on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: As a guess, your cross GCC installation might be broken, or possibly for the wrong ABI (32 vs 64 bit) vs your development machine.

Comment: Does this return the version? /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v It could also mean *-gcc may be incorrectly soft linked or may not be having execute permissions (+x) What does ls -l /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/ | grep "^l" return? (an l for link) What does ls -l /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3 return?

Comment: This leads to the same issue. For some reason that gcc executable cannot find the other executable in the same folder. You can see it in the screenshot above.


`gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: line 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3: command not found`

Comment: The first one returns nothing. The second one finds the file:


`gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ ls -l /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/ | grep "^l"
gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ ls -l /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gray gray 571736 Dec  1 15:58 /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
`

Comment: The gcc version I am using is in the tools directory.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out.

I just grabbed the crossbuild version of gcc (I think that is what it is)

```
sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

And then my new path is:

```
export CCPREFIX=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

And the build works perfectly!